# Sending serialized form to database

Tags: php, jquery, forms, serialization

I'm trying to send a serialized form to my database. I'm doing this because each form can have a different number of user-created input fields and wanted a simple way to store all the forms the same way. My question is that when I serialize the form, use JQuery to attach it to a hidden input field, and then send the the form and some other information to the database, the rest of the information is reaching the database but I still have a blank in where the serialized form is. If anyone could point out where I went wrong and/or explain how this should be done I'd be very grateful! Thank you very much!

Here is how I'm sending the data to the database:

```
$orderDate = mysql_prep($_POST["orderDate"]);
        $orderName = mysql_prep($_POST["orderName"]);
        $formSerialized = mysql_prep($_POST["formSerialized"]);


        $query = "INSERT INTO test (orderDate, orderName, orderSerialized) VALUES ('{$orderDate}', '{$orderName}', '{$orderSerialized}')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Here is the hidden field I am trying to attach the serialized form to:

```
<input type="hidden" id="phpVar" name="phpVar" value="<?php echo $var; ?>">
```

And here is the JQuery:

```
var formSerialized = $("form").serialize();
$("#phpval").val(formSerialized);
```

Comment: `mysql_prep` does what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, that is a custom function - just because I'm lazy lol:
`code`
function mysql_prep($string){
  global $connection; 
  
  $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $string);
  return $escaped_string; 
 }
`code`

Comment: why not just use prepared statements?

Comment: Pretty new to all this, currently looking up what a prepared statement is.

Comment: Do you think that would be a good idea if the form might end up having 100+ input fields?

Comment: Better use the same ids in html and js. $("#phpvar").val(formSerialized);

Comment: Also your php should use the name of the hidden input $_POST["phpvar"] and not the name of the js variable.

Comment: Last, but I guess not least, you should insert the variable in the db to which the value is assigned. VALUES ('{$orderDate}', '{$orderName}', '{$formSerialized}') Aargh!

Comment: Wow I screwed this up lol. I shouldn't have tried to continue from last night to this morning before I woke up. I kept thinking I just wasn't using MySQL correctly.

Comment: Thanks for being awesome mainguy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are serializing your form and then insert it into an element with id of phpval.

You should use the jQuery ajax function to send the serialized form and then post it to your php page.  ref. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var form = $('#my_awesome_form');

    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: You just blew my mind lol. Haven't used ajax before but am researching it now and this looks great.

Comment: Once I serialize it how do I post it to the php page without using an element like I did before?

Comment: See my example :) Your form start tag has the attribute action and in my example an id of my_awesome_form. jQuery get's the form and all it's content. We can then access the form action url with formatter('action');
<form id="my_awesome_form" action="php_file_to_call.php">

Comment: Okay awesome. Thanks! So once I'm back in the php page the serialized form is still under the same ID? So how can I gather that serialized form and send it to a database?

Comment: You can grab the inputs as you are use to with $_POST['input_name']

Comment: Oh. Okay. Thanks. But what if, as in this situation, I might have over a 100 inputs because they can be generated by the user?

Comment: It's not hard at all. You are just using javascript to submit the form to a page, without reloading. Same thing when you post on ur Facebook wall.
Look at http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ for more in-dept info and learn jQuery here : http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery